# How should i change the orientation of android date picker to portrait in tablet view.?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

How should i change the orientation of android date picker to portrait in tablet display?

```
<DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"

        />
```

By default, it have a landscape view for tablet, and portrait view for phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock your orientation to portrait via

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
if (rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == android.view.Surface.ROTATION_180) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

When you have completed the actions that require portrait orientation you can unlock the orientation with

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Of course, if it is an activity that you need to always be in portrait you can set the orientation of the activity specifically via the manifest file instead.

Comment: I want to change the orientation of date picker , not the  orientation of activity.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no way to do it directly via XML. However you can lock the orientation when the time picker is visible and then unlock it when has completed.

Comment: put that datepicker inside linear layout and set orientation of linear layout to portrait

Comment: did u mean orientation of linear layout to vertical?

Comment: @loldlock it doesn't change the orientation of date picker,  instead it changes the orientation of the whole activity.